# Add a message after saving an article

Tags: plugin, articles

Based on this question:. 
https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/24042/8968

I want to add the return code as a message after save to see if it was successful or not.

Can someone tell how I can do this?

Here is my Code:

```
class plgContentBk_onsave extends JPlugin
{

public function onContentAfterSave ($context, $article, $isNew)
{
// Do something
[Send a message after save]
return true;    
}
}
```

Comment: Please write your snippet from the other page directly here so that future researchers don't have to page jump to get the full story.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21741288/2943403

Comment: Please undelete your most recent question.  By sharing your experience, other Joomla users can benefit.  The right thing to do is to post a complete and educational answer to your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this->app->enqueueMessage($message, $type);
```

Where `$message` is the message string and `$type` is an optional type (message, warning, error or notice; defaults to message).

Comment: Thx: $application->enqueueMessage(JText::_($message), 'notice'); works for me